# have IntelliJ IDEA refresh the project and detect changed files

Tags: eclipse, file, intellij-idea, refresh

I'm using Eclipse for development because of all the things IntelliJ can't do (e.g. highlight all instances of a variable) and because IntelliJ is dog slow over a remote connection. But because I still don't have Maven integrated completely into Eclipse, I have to switch back to IntelliJ to compile and run my project using Tomcat.

How can I tell IntelliJ to detect all files that have changed on the file system and recompile them? (I don't want to manually open each changed file to get IntelliJ to detect the change.) In Eclipse I would just Refresh the project tree [**1**]...

**Footnotes**:

1. Eclipse has a feature (named "***Refresh Using native hooks or polling***") which you can enable  to automatically detect changes and synchronise the perspective when any underlying changes are detected in the filesystem (see images below). This is quite handy and eliminates the need to manually refresh the project when using build tools - where files/directories get created in the project directory structure.

Is there anything similar for Intellij (explicit setting or otherwise) that eliminates having to click a button to synchronize the view with filesystem changes?

[image: 'Refresh Using native hooks or polling' setting]

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use the "synchronize" button (two yellow arrows) or in short <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried this and it didn't work, but I could be mistaken. Frankly I managed to get everything converted to Eclipse and I'm looking back, so I'm assuming this is the correct answer, and will mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: Doesnt work for me, tho im doing Flash project and trying to reload my ANE but the compiled app seems to be using some cached  ane. Cant figure it out how to force Intellij to compile the newest ANE :S

Comment: It it does not work, you may try to check project settings and see whether the folder is excluded or not.

Comment: I guess a keyboard shortcut 'eliminates having to click a button', but it would be nice if IntelliJ just monitored the file system and always kept up-to-date. (I'm currently pretty neutral about which IDE is better, but this is one thing that Eclipse does better. And vim does better yet.)

Comment: Can be found under menu File > Synchronize.

Comment: By clicking **Synchronize** button manually was not solution in some case. That's not similar with eclipse's **Refresh Using native hooks or polling**. For instance , *I have a imageupload program.I save uploaded images to my projects's directory (eg:src/main/webapp/xxxx.jpg) and return url of its to UI to show this image. That is work on eclipse due to refresh using native hook or pooling but not in Intellij.*

Answer (score 8):

Intellij can highlight variable instances, you just need to enable it .
Further, if you invoke compile project,  Intellij will just compile changed files (and hotswap when possible, if you are in debug mode & deploying to e.g. tomcat)

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your Project in the left pane and click on "Synchronize"

You can see the status in the round circling icon at the bottom left of the IDE

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was posted a few years ago, but maybe this info will help someone in the future.  I was actually looking into a similar issue, and doing the following worked for me:

Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler and make sure "Make project automatically" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Click File>Synchronize (or) shortcut ctrl+Alt+Y

Answer (score 1):

There is a synchronise button in the tool bar. Click it and it will refresh the project explorer

[image: Synchronise button]