# NoClassDefFoundError with LuaJ

Tags: android, android-studio, luaj

I'm trying to use LuaJ in an Android Studio (V0.2.3) project.

I added the `luaj-jme-3.0-beta.jar` to the libs folder.

Under "Project Structure" libraries I added the project library `luaj-jme-3.0-beta.jar`.

In the build.gradle file under "dependancies" I added this line: `compile files('libs/luaj-jme-3.0-beta1.jar')`

In my MainActivty I call luaj:

```
import org.luaj.vm2.Globals;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.jme.JmePlatform;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Globals globals = JmePlatform.standardGlobals();
}
```

Compiling is succesfull, then after uploading the apk file to the target device I got this message:

```
08-18 16:59:25.533  11363-11363/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.luaj.vm2.lib.jme.JmePlatform
at de.ibr.luaj5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
```

I use apkananyser.jar to look in the apk file. It looks like the lua lib is not include in the apk file.

Im new to gradle, so how can I add the lua lib to the apk file? I've been Googling this for two days but I can't find a solution.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please share your `build.gradle` file's code.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile files('libs/luaj-jme-3.0-beta1.jar')
}

Answer (score 0):

After adding `luaj-jme-3.0-beta.jar` to your Project's Structure, right click on it and select `add as library`. 
Rest of your app seems fine, as you have added the compiling commands under the dependencies in your gradle file.

**EDIT:**
Please do follow these steps too, this is a common problem that you are facing.
1. While your application opened go to File => Close Project.
2. Open cmd (command promt) on your project's root location, i.e 'C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationProject\'
3. On the cmd, type gradlew clean, wait till it's done processing the command.
4. Reopen your application project in Android Studio.
5. Test run your application and it should work.

Comment: I can't find this menu item. Where I have to do this? In the "Project Structure" window or in the project tree?

Comment: Please follow this link, if you are unable to find the `add as library` option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij