# javac CLASSPATH issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsqlparser

This seems to be very trivial. But I'm stuck for a while.

My `CLASSPATH`:

```
jerry@jerry-OptiPlex-790:~/Desktop/SQLLite-experiment/java$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:./*:/home/jerry/Desktop/SQLLite-experiment/java/jsqlparser-0.7.0.jar
```

Output of `ll`:

```
jerry@jerry-OptiPlex-790:~/Desktop/SQLLite-experiment/java$ ll
total 980
drwxrwxr-x 2 jerry jerry   4096 Apr 21 19:25 ./
drwxrwxr-x 7 jerry jerry   4096 Apr 21 17:05 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jerry jerry 991221 Apr 21 17:25 jsqlparser-0.7.0.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jerry jerry    181 Apr 21 19:24 test.java
```

My `test.java` file:

```
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.StatementVisitor;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Output of `javac`:

```
jerry@jerry-OptiPlex-790:~/Desktop/SQLLite-experiment/java$ javac test.java 
test.java:1: error: package net.sf.jsqlparser.statement does not exist
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.StatementVisitor;
                                  ^
test.java:2: error: package net.sf.jsqlparser does not exist
import net.sf.jsqlparser.*;
^
2 errors
```

The below command also produces the same error:

```
jerry@jerry-OptiPlex-790:~/Desktop/SQLLite-experiment/java$ javac -cp "jsqlparser-0.7.0.jar:." test.java
```

The source for jsqlparser:
http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/docs/

Could anyone please help me out with this issue? I also tried using this library on IntelliJ but it wasn't getting recognized. I followed through the standard procedure of adding an external library as stated in: [How to add external library in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea)

FWIW I use `tmux`. Hope this isn't a issue with the CLASSPATH issue.

Comment: When you do import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.StatementVisitor in test.java does it give any error?

Comment: Oh, I use vim. So, unsure how it behaves in an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the solution I figured out after wasting hours. Seems stupid but still:... I just had to `unzip` the `jar` and use the `jar` file in the `lib` directory of the extracted `jar`.

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html) for how to set classpath using command line options to any of the java sdk tools - java, javac. The page shows how to set the environment variable CLASSPATH as well as how to use the switch -classpath.

In your case if you have the jar in the same directory as your source files, then you will need a command like this to compile -

```
javac -classpath . MyClass.java
```

and this to run

```
java -classpath . MyClass
```

You can also provide the full path to a jar file in the classpath and add multiple directories and jars. Such as -classpath .:/path/to/my.jar:/some/other/directory

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of this. But, as stated in the question, the procedures I tried which included the ones you mentioned doesn't work in my case.

Comment: try replacing the jar

Comment: Yup, I replaced the jar to another one `mail.jar`; the standard mail jar from oracle. It worked fine. So, I suppose it's a problem with the `jsqlparser` jar file.