# Add external library in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to use [this external library](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/reed-solomon/) in my Intellij Maven project. I have tried to do it like [official described](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#add_existing_lib) and like often recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project).
But always I try to type `ReedSolomon` or `com.backblaze.erasure.ReedSolomon`, `ReedSolomon` is marked red and Cntrl+b says "Cannot find declaration to go to". Also Alt+Enter gives me no posibility to import the class.
Other libraries are added and were recognized.

Isn't it possible to use this zip as external library? Do you have any ideas what I can try else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to first unzip the library. It is not a .jar archive, but a package.

So you could create a new package in your project: `com.backblaze.erasure`. There you copy/paste all *.java* files from the unzipped directory `javareedsolomon\com\backblaze\erasure`.

Hope this helps you :)