# How do I import scala.reflect.io.File into my project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-reflect

I am using IntelliJ IDE.

I want to `import scala.reflect.io.File` from the package - `scala-reflect-2.11.4`. But when I type in `import scala.reflect`, the compiler thinks that I am trying to use the `class reflect` from the package `scala-library-2.11.8`.

How do I force the compiler to use import the `class scala.reflect.File` from `scala-reflect-2.11.4`?

Comment: Compiler scans the class path. Sounds like you're just missing reflect.jar. I don't know without trying how Idea manages the class path. In general, `scala.reflect` can be located in multiple file locations.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using, and how are you managing dependencies?

Comment: Have you added the `jar` file as an [external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea#15960913)?