# Maven dependencies are downloaded but not recognized inside project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I want to build a project which has some external libraries. I included `pom.xml` file inside intellij and it downloaded all of required dependencies files from maven and put them as external libraries, but my project doesn't recognize them and gives compilation error. IDE screen attached below.

this is one of the compilation errors that I get:

```
Error:(29, 33) java: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
```

here is the my external libraries which I think are added correctly.
[image]

I don't have maven installed but I think IntelliJ handles it by it self.

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: It might be helpful to include the compilation error.  Also, it's generally frowned upon to post screenshots of code.  Better to include the code with the question as a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not java user but : do you have com.google.common.collect or com.google.common in your external library list ? As you are using it, i suppose it should be found there.

Comment: Can you share the pom.xml file also?

Comment: @SameeraB here is the `pom.xml` file: https://github.com/guoguibing/librec/blob/master/librec/pom.xml

Comment: @technico I added screen shot of my external libraries as described by here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea

Comment: @LexScarisbrick I added the compilation error(one of them)

Comment: Did you already try to force a resync with the `Reimport all Maven projects` (blue _refresh_ icon) button from the Maven tool-window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `mvn clean compile` either using Intellij or command line ?

Comment: I don't have maven installed.

Comment: @HadiAmiri there's a version [bundled with IJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/maven-settings-page.html)