# How to import java mysql connector to IntelliJ?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, import, connector

how can I import mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar file to IntelliJ? I was searching about hour but I cant find nothing.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How to add external library in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea), it have nothing in common with [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you use Gradle:**

Just add this line to build.gradle within `dependencies { ... }`:

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
```

**If you use Maven:**

Add these lines:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

**If you want to add it without using any build automation systems:**

Just drag & drop it to your project and right-click it and choose Add jar as library...