# How can build Apache POI in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java

I intend to create a Java project what needs DateUtil class from Apache POI. I use IntelliJ Idea 2017.2.5 development editor. I downloaded poi-src-3.17-20170915.tar.gz and poi-bin-3.17-20170915.tar.gz. I think the poi-bin-3.17 contains the jar files from poi-src-3.17 source files so I do not need use ant. Am I right? 
I would like to build Apache POI according to https://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html. I added the .jar files from poi-bin-3.17 according to [How to add external library in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea)
But I do not know how I should define all the source folders under src accordingly? 
I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a single class `DateUtil`, I think you better extract this file and put it direct to your project, include a big jar which has several megabytes just for only class is not a very good.

Answer (score 0):

Meantime I could solve this issue. I added the extracted poi-bin-3.17 into

```
File/Project Structure/Libraries
```

so I can import `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil` in my project and I can use `DateUtil.getExcelDate(date)` function.