# Intellij Idea plugin project development

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, plugins, difference, platform-sdk

I am new to Intellij idea plugin development! I refered to tutorials in https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics.html and developed sample plugins using the platform sdk and using gradle.

But if I am hoping to develop a plugin for a prject what would be the most best method? Based on reviews they prefer gradle but for me platform sdk seems to be easy. Is there any disadvantages of using platform sdk for a plugin development project?

Comment: It is all about automation. I personally do not use the Gradle way, too much magic and fiddling with the config.

Comment: @Meo but the problem is how   to develop the intellij plugin using maven since I have to import the JavaParser library  available at https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser-visited/tree/master/src/main/java/org/javaparser/examples/chapter1 using maven?

Comment: What? Maven? Either use Gradle, or no build tool.

Comment: @Meo how can import the library with out  a build tool? it states either to use gradle or maven! If I am not using gradle for plugin development and if maven can not be used with the platform sdk how can I import the library? :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea