# Getting error while runnign gatling project "object gatling is not a member of package io import io.gatling.app.Gatling"

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to run a test recorded as har script from browser and imported to the project in Intellij IDE. When I am running the project it is giving error:

```
object gatling is not a member of package io import io.gatling.app.Gatling
```

Below is the screenshot attached.

[image]

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Have you actually added the Gatling package to your project? There should be the relevant entries in your pom.xml file for getting the package from Maven Central. Please check if the library has been added to your project and let us know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065402/how-to-add-external-library-in-intellij-idea#15960913 and http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-1-getting-familiar-intellij-ide/intellij-import-dependencies-sbt-maven/ should help in finding it.

Comment: After changing the correct dependency in POM file. The build worked correctly, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment on your question, you need to add the Gatling package into your Maven build configuration in the `pom.xml` file. The IntelliJ Idea help page on [Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_add_module) has instructions to add a Maven package:

> Add a new Maven module to an existing project﻿
>
> You can add a Maven module to the project in which you are already
> working.
>
> - In the Project tool window, right-click the project folder and select
>   New | Module.
> - Alternatively, from the main menu, select File |
>   New | Module to open the New Module wizard.
>
> If you used main menu to add a module then the process of adding a module is the same as Creating a new Maven project.
>
> If you are adding sub modules by right-clicking the root folder then the process of adding a new module is shorter.
>
> - You need to specify the name of your module in the Name field.
>   The rest of the information is added automatically and you can use either the default settings or change them according to your preferences.