# IntelliJ IDEA watch external changes from sublime text

Tags: java, javascript, intellij-idea, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a project where I'm building JAVA using IDEA (resolving dependecies ...). But I am not a java developer and I do just frontend, so I have Idea opened and at the same time I have the same files opened in sublime text 3.

Problem is when **I change something in sublime text** these changes don't update files for Idea (**I have to click to Idea window to focus** and then it's updated) Is there any way how to watch files in Idea and then apply these external changes without this focus?

Thanks

Comment: checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599180/have-intellij-idea-refresh-the-project-and-detect-changed-files

Comment: I've read this while ago, unfortunately synchronization button is not working properly. Plus I don't want to click for every change. Prefect situation would be if I type something in sublime -> Idea automatically update files and I can see the changes live on the page.