# IntelliJ bug: project pane is not in sync and refresh button does not work

Tags: intellij-idea

From time to time my project pane in IntelliJ stops to reflect it's contents correclty. If I drag file from package to package it forget to show the result in the pane, so that I need to close and open nodes to refresh. It is annoying.

Is it possible to refresh content so that it starts to work ok?

**UPDATE**

`Refresh` button does not help. Even orphan nodes persist if it is pressed:

[image]

Only collapse/expand helps. But once you delete something more, you need to collapse/expand once more.

Comment: Have you tried to right click a class, package or module and click `Synchronize`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [have IntelliJ IDEA refresh the project and detect changed files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599180/have-intellij-idea-refresh-the-project-and-detect-changed-files)

Comment: @DarekKay sure; it doesn't help