# Cannot find symbol WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, websecurity

I'm trying to learn Spring Security by following this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

But I'm stuck on the setup phase.  The tutorial essentially tells me to add these items to my pom:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But my IDE complains that spring security doesn't exist:

[image]

I've tried other tutorials and have run into the same issue.  I don't understand.

I've tried to do a mvn clean install (the tutorial doesn't say to do that) but it didn't work.

Also tried File -> Invalidate Caches ... -> Invalidate and Restart in my IDE, that didn't help either.

Anybody know what the issue is?

Erros after running mvn clean install:

[image]

Comment: It's good first to determine if it's a code issue or an IDE issue.  From a command-line window, does "mvn clean install" work?  If not, forget about the IDE, it will never work there either, something would be missing in your POM.

Comment: If it's an IDE issue, it looks like you're using Visual Studio Code, that is better for front-end (JavaScript) development.  For Java, I'd recommend the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse instead, they're much more Java-focused and less likely to have hiccups in detecting libraries.

Comment: It fails if I do mvn clean install.  Though it appears that its only failing due to the library.  In fact, when I remove the red imports and the compilation errors and reinstall then it succeeds.  So I don't think its my code.  I'll attach the errors to the post.

I am using Intellij

Comment: OK, the failures from your mvn clean install are because you have two different types of User objects (only one of which can be imported at the top), and you're not explicitly qualifying them.  If you have a.User and b.User, instead of coding List<User> you need to do List<a.User> (assuming b.User is in the import statement).  Generally you want to get the mvn clean install working first (as Maven doesn't use an IDE, so the latter can't be the problem with Maven errors), then worry about the IDE not detecting libraries.  You can still use the IDE for changing code in the interim.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense!  But now my mvn clean install is succeeding but my IDEA is complaining about compile errors, so now it's definitely my IDE

Comment: May need to resynchronize your project in IntelliJ (circular arrow button), to pick up any new config in the pom.xml:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599180/have-intellij-idea-refresh-the-project-and-detect-changed-files#4599243 .  Resyncs are commonly needed when the pom changes.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a synchronize button on my Intellij.  The closest thing I have is "Reload All from Disk" (which does nothing).  In any case I closed and reopened Intellij but that didn't do anything either.  I've switched to Eclipse and it seems to work there but now Eclipse is complaining about my package, it doesn't like "package src.main.java.com.reactform.backend.reactformbackend" and prefers instead "package com.reactform.backend.reactformbackend" which is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221171/discussion-between-glen-mazza-and-mattang).